# resta con valores seleccionados de diferentes tablas

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo un inconveniente el cual espero me puedan ayudar, deseo sumar unos valores de una `tabla1` y que pueda restarlos de otros valores seleccionados de otra `tabla2` bajo condición de `tabla 2 like=´A%´` sumando estos valores y restándolos de la tabla 1 con valores  `like= 'B%'`

De antemano gracias

Comment: Qué has intentado hasta ahora? Qué es lo que te falla de ello?

Comment: Gracias, he intentado separalos primero con la condicion like para que me tome solo los valores 'n', pero al momento de ejecutar la resta me toma toda la columna y no lo seleccionado

Comment: Sería extraordinario que publicaras lo que has intentado para saber dónde estás fallando colega :)

Comment: me sugirieron un procedimiento almacenado que se invoque en la resta pero no estoy seguro

Comment: De hecho mi recomendación sería exactamente esa (crear un sp) si notas que la complejidad es mucha - refiriendose a que debes realizar cálculos o la operación comprende dos tablas o más -, pero te insisto en que publiques lo que trataste en la pregunta para poder contextualizarnos mejor

Comment: Select distinct f9930_ts as fecha, f5450_id_co_docto as centro_operativo,
 sum( f9930_vlr_bruto)as [Total_Bruto],
 sum (f9930_precio_uni) as [Precio_Uni],
 Sum (f9930_vlr_neto) as [Neto],
 sum (f9930_vlr_dscto_linea) as cantidad, sum (f9930_vlr_imp) as impuestoFrom t9930_pdv_a_movto_venta, t5450_acum_inventarios
where f5450_id_co_docto like '%001%' and t9930_pdv_a_movto_venta.f9930_id_fecha_factura 
between  '2018-02-02'and '2018-08-31' 
group by  f9930_ts, f5450_id_co_docto
order by  fecha

Comment: Select  distinct f120_id,f120_rowid,f120_referencia,f120_descripcion_corta,f131_id,f131_rowid_item_ext,f131_id_unidad_medida,f9930_guid,f9930_guid_doctof9930_rowid_item_ext,f9930_id_fecha_factura,f9930_vlr_neto,f9930_fecha_ts_creacionfromt120_mc_itemsinnerjoint131_mc_items_barrasont120_mc_items.f120_rowid=t131_mc_items_barras.f131_rowid_item_extinnerjoint9930_pdv_a_movto_ventaont131_mc_items_barras.f131_rowid_item_ext=t9930_pdv_a_movto_venta.f9930_rowid_item_extWHEREt9930_pdv_a_movto_venta.f9930_id_fecha_factura  between '2018-08-01' and'2018-10-04' and f131_id like '%03%'order by f131_id asc

Comment: disculpa el formato de la ultima

Comment: @JoseGil, no publiques código en los comentarios. Edita tu pregunta y agrega la información que hace falta. Por ejemplo, además de la sentencia o sentencias que has intentado y sus errores o problemas, en casos de este tipo viene muy bien publicar a manera de ejemplo unos cuantos datos de cada tabla y el resultado que esperas obtener con dichos datos. Para más información, por favor lee [ask].

Comment: al pasar el codigo borre algunos caracteres y no lo note....disculpas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te sugiero un hagas un CTE (Common Table Expression ) que es básicamente una tabla temporal, solo si los datos de las tablas no son muy extensos.

Sería algo así

```
WITH CTE_Tabla2 AS
(
    SELECT Valor FROM Tabla2 WHERE FILTRO LIKE '%N%'
)
SELECT SUM(T1.Valor)-T2.Valor FROM TABLA1 T1, CTE_Tabla2 T2
WHERE T1.FILTRO LIKE '%A%'
GROUP BY GRUPO
```

Puedes encontrar mas información de como usar CTE aquí 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Gracias¡ bendiciones¡

Answer (score 0):

```
Select distinct f9930_ts as fecha, f5450_id_co_docto as centro_operativo,
 sum( f9930_vlr_bruto)as [Total_Bruto]- sum f9930_vlr_bruto,
 sum (f9930_precio_uni) as [Precio_Uni],
 Sum (f9930_vlr_neto) as [Neto],
 sum (f9930_vlr_dscto_linea) as cantidad, sum (f9930_vlr_imp) as impuesto
From t9930_pdv_a_movto_venta, t5450_acum_inventarios
where f5450_id_co_docto like '%001%' and t9930_pdv_a_movto_venta.f9930_id_fecha_factura 
between  '2018-02-02'and '2018-08-31' 
group by  f9930_ts, f5450_id_co_docto
order by  fecha
```

Comment: por favor lee [answer] pues aunque se te agradece el apoyo, el colocar solo código se considera de baja calidad; dale editar y añade una explicación; piensa que esto no solo debe servirle a quien preguntó sino al resto de usuarios que pudieran llegar a consultarla

Comment: gracias por la observacion, soy nuevo en esto...